# Conversion from string yyyyMMddHHmmss to type integer is not valid

Tags: .net, vb.net, type-conversion, nullable

I am trying to write up a system that passes its value to the front end via an MVC web service.

While it's running, I keep encountering this error and I cannot get past it; I have isolated it to this line of code but I cannot see what is wrong with it. This is the line of code, the timestamp and the error:

[image: code]
[image: timestamp]
[image: error]

I cannot divulge too much code as some of it is sensitive, however this is generic. If you require more information I will do my best to provide it.

Comment: What you need to do is use [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360). It will enable Visual Studio to tell you where data types do not match up. For example, the code you show implies that you are trying to store a string in a Integer or DateTime variable, which is wrong.

Comment: It's already on and adding the tag to the top of the code didn't do anything

Comment: Is the type of `paymentRequest.TimeStamp` definitely DateTime? I know it looks like it is from the #numbers PM#, but is that what it is declared as? Does `CDate(paymentRequest.TimeStamp).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")` make it work?

Comment: That's worth checking

Comment: paymentRequest.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now

Comment: If `paymentRequest.TimeStamp` has a type of `Object` then that will work but the `.ToString()` won't work as intended.

Comment: Public Property Timestamp As String

its built with
Dim viewModel as new PaymentPageViewModel With { .Timestamp = paymentRequest.Timestamp.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
}

there is other stuff within that. i have since added CDate(paymentRequest.TimeStamp)

before this its stored as part of an object with the type been "Date?"

Comment: If the type of `paymentRequest.TimeStamp` is `Date?` (i.e. `Nullable(Of DateTime)`) then you would need `paymentRequest.TimeStamp.Value` to get its value, and so the code snippet should be `.Timestamp = paymentRequest.TimeStamp.Value.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")`.

Comment: well after some testing i had to rebuild and redeploy to get it to register the change but the CDate seemed to have fixed it, i still have some reservations given this code apparently works for others so i want to know why however for me i am just looking at knocking down each bug as it comes until this works. If you want to post as an answer rather than comment i will register it as the fix for this issue.

Comment: When you assign a value to a Nullable type, you just use `variable = x`, but to get the value from it you need `y = variable.Value`. The vital information to make it work properly was revealed when you said it has the type `Date?`. It really should have put a red squiggly line under the problem in Visual Studio - perhaps the Option Strict On is faulty in the project - if you toggle it off and on again maybe it will persuade it to notice it.

Comment: Perhaps, this isn't great code which makes debugging a little tricky as on paper it should have worked. it should never be null by the time it gets to this point though given its populated in the initial request. I will take on board adding .value however i will not add it as currently encapsulating it within CDate() has fixed this issue. My other issue is related to RSA within another project so unrelated to the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the type of `paymentRequest.TimeStamp` is `Date?` (i.e. `Nullable(Of DateTime)`) then you would need `paymentRequest.TimeStamp.Value` to get its value, and so the code snippet should be

```
.Timestamp = paymentRequest.TimeStamp.Value.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
```

Although it is undocumented ([as far as I can find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(vb.CDate)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396)), you can also use `CDate` to get the date from a `Date?` thus: `.Timestamp = CDate(paymentRequest.TimeStamp).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")`.

You may wish to avoid using an undocumented feature, as it could change without notification in later versions.

Both ways will fail with an error of

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Nullable object must have a value.'

if `paymentRequest.TimeStamp.HasValue` is `False`.

---

Perhaps confusingly, the documentation for the [Nullable.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) says that

> The ToString property returns the string yielded by calling the ToString property of the object returned by the Value property.

however, it should be noted that this only applies to the ToString() method with *no* arguments.